# MacBook stops sending video signal to USB-C monitor after some time and I'm stumped

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a M1 MacBook Air and some time ago I purchased a HP u28 monitor that supports USB-C connection and provides up to 65w to charge the laptop. At the beginning everything worked great. All I had to do was to connect the USB-C cable that was provided with the monitor and I'd have image on the screen and power on the laptop.

Then, a couple of weeks later, out of nowhere, the monitor stopped receiving video input from the laptop. It would still charge, but the monitor would say "USB-C Inactive" and the Mac would not detect any external monitor.

I thought then that perhaps the problem was the cable provided by HP and instead of contacting them I purchased another USB-C to USB-C cable, this one from Cable Matters. It worked. The problem seemed to be solved. Then a couple of weeks later I had exactly the same problem again, and now neither cable works. The Apple cable that came with my MacBook for charging also doesn't work, though it only happened to me to test it now.

All cables charge the laptop, none passes on image signal. I don't have another USB-C computer to test, but the monitor works fine connected via either DisplayPort or HDMI to a desktop computer running Linux.

Restarting the Mac or doing a factory reset on the monitor changes nothing. I have no idea what's going on here.

Edit: I did something that worked, I removed the monitor from the wall outlet and plugged it in again to power. Factoring resetting did not work but unplugging from power and plugging it back again did. No idea why this worked this time and honestly can't remember if I did unplug it last time (when replacing cables).

Edit 2: I don't have another computer that can do USB-C video, but I tested the cables with an external SSD and they were both working fine for data.

Comment: The next step in troubleshooting is to test the cables using a different computer (the Linux) one with the monitor.  I can't see cables failing in this manner.  You'll also want to test out on a different port on the MacBook

Comment: The Macbook charging cable won't pass data. Have you tried connecting to another USBC port on the MBA?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tested both cables with an external SSD (the two cables other than the Apple one, which indeed is only for charging). I couldn't test video output with another computer since my Linux desktop doesn't support USB-C video, but both cables are okay for data transfers. I also tried both USB-C ports on my MacBook Air (it only has 2), with identical results.

Comment: I noticed in your edit that power cycling you monitor resolves the issue.  This indicates a hung state of a USB port (chipset) on the Mac or monitor. Let’s  narrow it down.  Next time this happens, power cycle your Mac to see if it fixes it.

Comment: I did try restarting the Mac a few times, to no avail. I also thought of resetting PRAM/SMC, but learned that those don't apply to Macs with Apple Silicon. I also tried to turn the monitor on and off on the power switch and that didn't work either. The only thing that seemed to have worked this time was physically disconnecting the monitor from the mains and then reconnecting it.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my M2 MBA. External monitor is connected via Apple "USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter" (a2119).
When I connect power to my MBA via USB-C or MagSafe 3 my external monitor will flicker on and off. Interestingly when I tested with a Thunderbolt -> HDMI adapter the same external monitor is behaves normally when I connect power (USB-C or Magsafe) directly to my MBA. So I think the issue is related to how my MBA handles power when using USB-C -> HDMI -> External monitor. Perhaps something to do with USB-C PD negotiation?

Comment: I remember (vaguely) about some HP and Dell monitors would just stop working for no reason causing the cables to begin to fail.  Also....there's no such thing as USB-G. What you have is USB 3.0 (or 4) on Type-C connectors. The USB 3/4 chips could be failing.